# Rauch comparison theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, vector-fields

I am currently reading Chavels "Riemannian Geometry: A Modern Introduction". On page 86 he gives the following definition of Rauch's comparison theorem:

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma:[0,\beta]\rightarrow M$ a normed geodesic with $\gamma (0)=p$ such that $\mathcal{K}\leq\delta$ for all sections along $im(\gamma)$.

- If $Y\in \mathcal{J}^{\perp}$, then function $|Y|$ on $im(\gamma)$ satisfies $|Y|''+\delta|Y|\geq 0\quad (\star)$
- If $\Psi$ is a solution for $(\star)$ with $\Psi(0)=|Y|(0)$ and $\Psi'(0)=|Y|'(0)$, then \begin{align*}
  (\frac{|Y|}{\Psi})'\geq 0 \quad (1)& &|Y|\geq \Psi\quad(2)
  \end{align*}
- We have equality in $(2)$ on $t_0\in(0,\beta)$ iff $\mathcal{K}(Y,\gamma')=\delta$ on all $[0,t_0]$ and there exists a parallel unit vector field $X$ along $\gamma$ for which $Y(t)=\Psi(t)X(t)$ on all of $[0,t_0]$.

How does that connect to the [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauch_comparison_theorem) definition of the theorem comparing to manifolds? I don't see the connection even if Chavel says in a remark these two formulations are related.

Edit: $\mathcal{J}^{\perp}$ are the Jacobi fields perpendicular to $\gamma'$.

Comment: Not completely sure how to fully answer, but seeing that he assumes the sectional curvature is bounded above by a constant $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$, rather than the sectional curvature of another manifold, this might be some special case where the $\tilde{M}$ (in the wikipedia article you linked) is a Riemannian manifold of constant sectional curvature, or sectional curvature bounded below.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, but there needs to be more, otherwise it would have been sufficent to just present [Bonnet-Meyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem) and Cartan hadard. Somhow in that inequality is more inromation but i dont know how to understand the inequalities. I guess i can get from there again to the two manifold case but i can't see how to proof it. The Chapter in Chavel doesn't give a hint either.